# Storing boolean datas and textview datas in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to store a boolean variable and textview text on the device the app is running, so that even after clearing in recent apps i can use the recent booleab states to make changes remain the same. Or is there any way to get the last state even after clearing the app from the recent apps or onDestroy

Answer (score 2):

You should check out Shared Preferences in Android.

Write to Shared Preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

Read from Shared Preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

Comment: perhaps it would have been appropriate to mention the your code is straight out of android's documentation?

Comment: onCreate the value is set to it default

Answer (score 1):

@apelsoczi's answer is essentially correct, but here is a more detailed example which also includes boolean values, and String values, as asked in your question.

First get a reference to your apps Shared Preferences like this: 
`SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Then save your string and your boolean like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(YOUR BOOLEAN KEY, YOUR BOOLEAN);
    editor.putString(YOUR STRING KEY, YOUR TEXT VIEW STRING);
    editor.commit(); // if commit is not called then data not saved!
```

To retrieve the values do this:

```
boolean b = prefs.getBoolean(YOUR BOOLEAN KEY, OPTIONAL DEFAULT VALUE IF ITS NOT FOUND);
String s = prefs.getString(YOUR STRING KEY, OPTIONAL DEFAULT VALUE IF ITS NOT FOUND);
```

Shared Preferences is a way to store simple key value pairs of data - very useful for settings. For example say you have a value false for your boolean, and you want to save it, so what you do is you pass in a name for it (passing a name is important because you need that name to retrieve the value) and the actual value to save. When you want to retrieve it, you again pass in the name you had assigned it when saving it.

Comment: What is that boolean key?

Comment: its just a name that you provide - e.g. "myBoolean".

Comment: Its not working. Is there any other ways. Please help